# Generic 2D Point as input in C++

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am writing generic code for a template library. My input is supposed to be or to contain some form of 2D coordinates. For the sake of being generic, my code will expect the following two functions to be implemented in user code somehow:

```
template <typename T, typename CoordinateType>
CoordinateType get_x(const T&);

template <typename T, typename CoordinateType>
CoordinateType get_y(const T&);
```

Nevertheless, I was thinking: can I relieve from the user of my library the burden of implementing these two functions for some very trivial cases? Maybe by using SFINAE with some default implementations of those two functions?

For example, if `T` has `.x` and `.y` public members just use those, or if the given `T` has `.x()` and `.y()` accessors just call them, or maybe `.get_x()` and `.get_y()` as well as `.getX()` and `.getY()` and so on...

Comment: I think yes, because that's pretty close to how `std::being()`/`std::end()` and ilk work.

Comment: What C++ standard are you targeting?

Comment: @MaxLanghof C++17

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [`std::is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) and `if constexpr` (so C++17 compatible):

```
template<class T>
using member_x = decltype(std::declval<T&>().x);
template<class T>
using member_y = decltype(std::declval<T&>().y);

template<class T>
using accessor_x = decltype(std::declval<T&>().x());
template<class T>
using accessor_y = decltype(std::declval<T&>().y());

template<class T>
using brackets = decltype(std::declval<T&>()[0]);


template<class T>
auto get_x_impl(const T& vec)
{
  if constexpr (std::experimental::is_detected_v<member_x, T>)
    return vec.x;
  else if constexpr (std::experimental::is_detected_v<accessor_x, T>)
    return vec.x();
  else if constexpr (std::experimental::is_detected_v<brackets, T>)
    return vec[0];
  else
    return get_x(vec);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/_Soaeb

However, there's still a problem with specializing `get_x` - the return type can't be deduced but must be specified in the call (but the library can't know what type the getter should return!). Following where the standard is going, it is discouraged to provide function templates as customization points, class template are more robust. That would help here:

1. The library provides a class template for users to specialize (possibly in a separate namespace):

   ```
   template<class T>
   struct getter;
   ```
2. The library uses it:

   ```
   return getter<T>::get_x(val);
   ```
3. The user specializes it:

   ```
   template<>
   struct getter<TypeToSpecializeFor>
   {
       static auto get_x(const TypeToSpecializeFor&) { /*...*/ }
       static auto get_y(const TypeToSpecializeFor&) { /*...*/ }
   };
   ```

https://godbolt.org/z/W4LPt8

The naming of all the involved identifiers is of course up to taste.

Further reading: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/03/19/customization-points-for-functions/

Comment: `std::is_detected` seems to be in experimental even for C++17